# RESTful API with optional parameters

Tags: rest, api, model-view-controller, parameters

Following are three Get controller actions in my API:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int page = 1) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string table) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string table, int id) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

How can I edit the middle function to accept an optional page parameter as does the first? When I edit it to

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string table, int page = 1) {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

I get a message saying there's already a Get member with the same parameter types.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify middle method at all; delete it.  Then, make `id` optional on the last method.

Otherwise, give the middle method a name other than `Get`.

Comment: These are GET methods for an API, so I think renaming is out of the question. I need to differentiate between a call for table, page = 7 and table id = 215.  I don't see how to do that with a single optional parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by making the middle method contain an optional string parameter:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string table, string page = "1") {
```

Then I can parse the string to an integer. It's ugly, but it works, and it keeps me moving forward. (Anyone has a better idea, I'm open to suggestions!)

Comment: I just wanted to mention that your question doesn't contain enough detail to justify this sort of solution. I understand that sometimes a contrived example is more convenient than real world code but contrived examples can lead others astray. Just something to keep in mind the next time you post a question